# When trying to make a countdown by 0.10 it prints wrong thing

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm trying to make a countdown timer for iOS and when I try to make it go down by 0.10 and when I run the program it after like 8.2, 8.1, it starts printing like this 7.900000000, 7.800000012 something like this.

[image: Here what it prints]

And also it's supposed to stop at 0 but

[image: stops here]

But it works perfectly when making it go down by 0.25, or .5 or 1.

Here is my code.

```
var seconds = 10.0
var timer = Timer()

@IBAction func startPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    startBtn.isHidden = true
    clickedTxt.isHidden = false
    numClicked.isHidden = false
    tapView.isEnabled = true
    timerTxt.isHidden = false
    secs.isHidden = false

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.counter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func counter()
{
    if(seconds > 0.0)
    {
        seconds -= 0.1
        secs.text = "\(seconds)"
    } else {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?s=1|16.6051

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing an effect of the way floating point numbers are formatted, essentially.  And you can read more about that in [the other question rmaddy pointed you to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken?s=1%7C16.6051).

I suspect you mostly want to format that label nicely.  In that case you can do something like:

```
secs.text = String(format:"%.1f", secs)
```

where you replace ".1" with however many places after the decimal you want.

Comment: This solves the output issue, but it doesn't address the problem of stopping at `0`.

Comment: Instead of testing whether it is greater than 0.0, test whether it is greater than the error value you are able to tolerate. Something like `if (seconds > 0.0001)`.

Comment: Thank you Aaron Golden and Price Ringo , It works now.

Comment: Aaron is it like the set precision in c++??